# Function and var with same name in a lisp-1?

Tags: clojure, memoization

If Clojure is lisp-1 and I have a function m, how is it possible to also have a var m that refers to a memoized version of the function m?

`(defn m .....)`

`(def m (memoize m))`

This is from the PragPub Clojure book by Halloway. I can't understand what's going on here, since functions and vars share the same namespace in Clojure as a lisp-1.

Comment: It's the same m. memoize gets passed m which is evaluated and bound to it's argument before it's redefined with its result. The original function is only accessable from the closure created by memoize.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

On p72 in `Joy of Clojure`:

> Lisp-1 uses the same name resolution for function and value
>   bindings... Because the same name-resolution scheme is used for
>   functions and their arguments, there's a real possibility of shadowing
>   existing functions with other locals or Vars.

So shadowing(or rebinding) vars is possible, like in your code:

```
(defn m ...)

(def m (memoize m))
```

`(memoize m)` returns the memoized version of function and this function is re-bound(override) to `m`. That's it.